# How to add dynamically <li> tags in jquery list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In the moment I can add li tags to my list with script. But how can I add dynamically li tags in a function in .js? Hopefully I will see a good example.
Below is my code. Thanks!

```
<div data-role="page" id="searchPage" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="b" id="searchListUl">
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#searchListUl").append('<li data-filtertext="Apple"><a href="#">Apple</a></li>');
  $("#searchListUl").listview('refresh');</script></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean *"in a function"* ?

Comment: e.g. function addLi() {
 return '<li data-filtertext="Apple"><a href="#">Apple</a></li>';
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your function would be something like:

```
var addItem = function(item){
    $("#searchListUl").append('<li data-filtertext="'+item+'"><a href="#">'+item+'</a></li>');
}
```

You can call it with:
`addItem("apple")`

Comment: good point, but who in my html calls addItem("apple")? Can you give an example please.

Comment: When you need it :) For example: if you have a button with the id `myButton`, you would do it like that: `$("#myButton").on("click", function(){addItem("apple")})`

Answer (score 0):

If you with "dynamic" mean that you want to be able to append list items without knowing the name ("Apple"), you could make a generic function, using the jQuery function used to create elements:

```
function add(name) {
    var $li = $("<li>").attr("data-filtertext", name)
                       .appendTo("#searchListUI");

    $("<a>").attr("href", "#")
            .text(name)
            .appendTo($li);
}
```

---

You could use it as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="searchPage" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="b" id="searchListUl">
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  add("Apple");
  $("#searchListUl").listview('refresh');</script></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to append list item without knowing the names. How can I call this function in my html?

Comment: @somehut: "Calling in HTML" does not make much sense - you can call it in JavaScript like `add("Apple")` and it will append the list item.

Comment: And how can I refresh my list after that?

Comment: @somehut: I guess calling `$("#searchListUl").listview('refresh');` afterwards - first append list items and then refresh the listview.

Comment: Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' with $("#searchListUl").listview('refresh');

Comment: @somehut: But you were able to call it in the original code? You could just replace the append code with `add("Apple")` and the rest should still work.

Comment: If I call your original function, I will see an empty list.

Comment: @somehut: I don't quite get what you're pointing at; have a look at my edit.

Answer (score -2):

It should be noted that using .append() in the way described in many of these answers will directly vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.  If strings are being pulled from a data source that can be influenced by users, then a user can put raw HTML, and when .append() is called, the raw HTML will get directly injected into the DOM.  Script tags are especially dangerous.  Once you can run arbitrary javascript in someones session, an attacker can grab their cookies, their private information, and even passwords in some circumstances, all without the victim knowing.

Always ALWAYS use .text() to set the text of an element.  In jquery, .text() will properly HTMLEncode characters when it needs to.  If you have experience with SQL, you can think of .append($RANDOM_STRING) the same way that you would think of conn.exec($RANDOM_STRING).  By their very nature, they are vulnerable to injection and should be avoided at all costs.

I'm sure code from these examples have already been copied and pasted, and are now in use all over the internet, and that sucks.  Please get the word out, .append() will append HTML, not just text, so improper use will let attackers inject raw HTML into your DOM.

Comment: Injecting raw HTML can always be done by the user through the console, whether you are using `append()` or not. But this should not pose any XSS danger vulnerabilities unless you are saving the generated html to a database or alike, and that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: There is zero mention of Cross Site Scripting.

Comment: Hey @pierce, if you want to discuss another answer it's generally better to leave a comment on that answer.